# HTML5 History Tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, pushstate

Anyone knows of any good tutorial/guide that explains a proper approach for using HTML5 History with Pushstate and Onpopstate event?

Comment: For what it's worth; the HTML5 State Functionality is only available to HTML5 Browsers. So perhaps you may want to use something like [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) which provides a backwards compatible experience to HTML4 Browsers (including support for data and titles, and replaceState functionality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Just an add-on, the manipulation of history using the above will be only for Firefox or rather Gecko 2 and not for webkit right ?

Comment: @Viraj: The fact that this article is placed on mozilla developer network does not mean it is true only for firefox. This is actually true for most modern browsers, it is one of the best features of html5